# Calculation of average of sine wave based on area under the curve and amplitude

Tags: functions, trigonometry, numerical-methods

Is it possible to derive analytically the mean value of the sine wave function (expressed as $f(x) = mean + A*\sin(x)$) based on known area under the curve and amplitude ($A$) (for illustration of what I mean please see below.  Or it has only a numerical solution? Thank you for any suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Why ''functional analysis'' and ''analyticity'' as tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use $k$ for the mean value, so $f(x)=k+A\sin(x)$ and $V$ for the area.  The curve passes through $0$ when $x=\arcsin (-\frac kA)$ so we have $$V=2\int_{\arcsin(-\frac kA)}^{\frac \pi 2} (k+A\sin x) \ dx\\
=2(kx|_{\arcsin(-\frac kA)}^{\frac \pi 2})-2(A \cos x)|_{\arcsin(-\frac kA)}^{\frac \pi 2}\\=k\pi-2k\arcsin(-\frac kA)-2\sqrt{1-\frac{k^2}{A^2}}$$
and the mix of inverse trig and the square root make me think a numerical solution is in your future.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick analysis and response. I thought that a numerical solution will be inevitable in this case. Hopefully, I will be able to solve it.