# Calculation of shift coefficient of sine wave based on area under the curve and amplitude

Tags: trigonometry

Is it possible to derive analytically the value of the shift coefficient ($m$) of the sine wave function (expressed as $f(x) = m + A*\sin(x)$) based on known area under the curve (both positive and negative)?.  Or it has only a numerical solution?

Comment: Exactly what area is known?

Comment: the positive and the negative area. look at the figure https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2144186/calculation-of-average-of-sine-wave-based-on-area-under-the-curve-and-amplitude. the problem is similar but i would like to obtain mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean about calculating the value of $m$ in terms of the depicted area, I am afraid there is not a closed form solution, only the numerical solution already included in the cited answer.